# Django permissions when using Django Rest Framework + VueJs as a front

Tags: django, vue.js, django-rest-framework, django-views

My question address to the usage of **Django permission architecture** even when the front is on `Vue.js` and data is requested/responded through `Django REST framework`.

I am a little confused about being able to use default permission libraries of Django when the app is combined with `Rest Framework` and `VueJs`:

from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required, permission_required

```
@permission_required('pobapp.can_add_instance')
@login_required
def addEmployeeInstance(request):
    return render(request, 'pobapp/search.html')
```

If not, how can I restrict some data and pages for specific users? For example, if I only wanted to let authenticated users to view some specific pages?

Answer (score -2):

If you want to restrict a logged user in pages, first, you should define a Role and a  Resource model for User model.

Then, you can define a permission class for controlling this restriction. for example my permission class for this purpose is like this,

```
class IsAuthRolePermission(permissions.BasePermission):

    def has_permission(self, request, view):

        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            try:
                obj = Resource.objects.get(name=view.__class__.__name__,
                                       roles__in=request.user.roles.all())
                return True
            except Resource.DoesNotExist:
                return False
        else:
            return False
```